# Upper and lower limits: sequence

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I have to calculate the upper limit and the lower limit of the following sequence:

$$a_n=\frac{1+2n(-1)^n}{1+3n}$$

---

As I know that the upper limit of $a_n$ is the limit of the supreme of $a_n$ when $n$ goes to infinity, I've tried to calculate the derivative of $a_n$ and then equal to $0$. But I don't know how to clear it.

Giving different values to $n$, I've seen that $a_n$ oscillates.

I don't know what more to do, I'm stuck...

Comment: What happens if n is even and if n is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the sequence into two subsequences $\{a_{2n}\}$ and $\{a_{2n+1}\}$. Now see that $ a_{2n} = \frac{1+4n}{1+6n} $ and $a_{2n+1} = -\frac{4n+1}{6n+4}$.

Again, $ \\ n\gt 1 \implies 2n\gt 2 \implies 24n^2+30n+5 \gt 24n^2+28n+7 \implies \frac {1+4(n+1)}{1+6(n+1)} \gt \frac {1+4n}{1+6n} \implies a_{2n+2} \gt a_{2n}$ i.e. monotone increasing.

Similarly we can show $a_{2n+1} > a_{2n+3}$ i.e. monotone decreasing.

And it's easy to see $a_{2n+1} \lt a_{2n}$.

Therefore $\\sup \ a_n = \ lim \ a_{2n} = \ \frac{4}{6}$.

Therefore $inf \ a_n = \ lim \ a_{2n+1} = -\frac{4}{6}$.

Comment: If I'm not wrong $ a_{2n} < a_{2n+2}  $

Comment: @Maialen isn't that what I've written?

Answer (score 1):

If you find the limit of the even indexed sequence and the odd indexed sequence, then you can prove, that every other sub-sequence must converge to one of these limits (or not converge at all).
To prove that a sub-sequence can't converge to anything else, notice that any sub-sequence the you take would have an infinite amount of elements from at least on of the sets